# How to mirror apt repo with Acquire-By-Hash using debmirror

Tags: apt, debmirror

I mirror some apt repositories using debmirror. I'm working on upgrading all hosts from 16.04 to 20.04, and am running into an issue, where in 20.04 `apt update` fails, because it can't download the `by-hash` urls for packages files for one of the repos. the `Release` and `InRelease` files for this repo contain `Acquire-By-Hash: yes` upstream. However, debmirror doesn't seem to be aware of this, and isn't mirroring any of the `by-hash` files, so the end client can't get the files by hash.

My first thought was to add something to remove the `Acquire-By-Hash` lines in a step after running `debmirror`. But then I realized that would break the signature on the Release files.

I suppose I could try to parse the InRelease file, and download the by-hash files myself. But that would be pretty complicated.

I might be open to switching to a different tool if has similar functionality to debmirror, but I haven't really found anything that supports this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure about `debmirror`, as I'm using [`squid-deb-proxy`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=squid-deb-proxy) for about 1.5 years without problems. It allows me to save bandwidth while doing package download and systems upgrades.

Comment: Unfortuanately, I don't think squid-deb-proxy works for my use case. I use debmirror to periodically take snapshots of the current apt repo, and different environments use different ages of snapshots, because 1. I want to test updates in non-production enviroments before updating in prod, and 2. I want to be sure packages are available regardless of the status of the upstream repo.